# Calculate last 12 Months + Sum of all transaction before last 12 months

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005

Wondering if you could help me with a query?

Working in the financial sector and my sql is a bit rusty. I need to return some data that we need to transfer to another database.

I have put together the following table for test reason.

I have 2 accounts, 1 and 2, each account has 2 years of transactions.

My attempt

```
    SELECT TOP 12 
    tt.AccountNo,
    tt.Amount,
    tt.CreatedDate,
    --Get Sum(Amount) of all transaction  before last 12 month
    Startingbalance=(SELECT sum(Amount)
                   FROM TransactionsTest tt2 
                  WHERE tt.AccountNo=tt2.AccountNo
                  AND --exclude last 12 months)
    FROM    TransactionsTest tt
    --WHERE tt.AccountNo=1
    GROUP BY tt.AccountNo,tt.Amount,tt.CreatedDate
    ORDER BY tt.CreatedDate desc
```

Task:

Return last 12 transactions for each account + each account must return a "StartingBalance"
StartingBalance=Sum(Amount) of  all transaction before the last 12 months.

Any suggestions how I could do it?

Many thanks

```
        BEGIN TRANSACTION;
    IF object_id(N'TransactionsTest', 'U') IS NOT NULL
        DROP TABLE TransactionsTest
    GO

    CREATE TABLE [dbo].[TransactionsTest](
        [Id] [int] NOT NULL,
        [AccountNo] [int] NOT NULL,
        [Amount] [decimal](18, 2) NOT NULL,
        [CreatedDate] [datetime] NOT NULL
    ) ON [PRIMARY]

    GO

    INSERT INTO [dbo].[TransactionsTest]([Id], [AccountNo], [Amount], [CreatedDate])
    SELECT 1, 1, 10.00, '20120128 00:00:00.000' UNION ALL
    SELECT 2, 1, 10.00, '20120228 00:00:00.000' UNION ALL
    SELECT 3, 1, 10.00, '20120328 00:00:00.000' UNION ALL
    SELECT 4, 1, 10.00, '20120428 00:00:00.000' UNION ALL
    SELECT 5, 1, 10.00, '20120528 00:00:00.000' UNION ALL
    SELECT 6, 1, 10.00, '20120628 00:00:00.000' UNION ALL
    SELECT 7, 1, 10.00, '20120728 00:00:00.000' UNION ALL
    SELECT 8, 1, 10.00, '20120828 00:00:00.000' UNION ALL
    SELECT 9, 1, 10.00, '20120928 00:00:00.000' UNION ALL
    SELECT 10, 1, 10.00, '20121028 00:00:00.000' UNION ALL
    SELECT 11, 1, 10.00, '20121128 00:00:00.000' UNION ALL
    SELECT 12, 1, 10.00, '20121228 00:00:00.000' UNION ALL
    SELECT 13, 1, 10.00, '20130128 00:00:00.000' UNION ALL
    SELECT 14, 1, 10.00, '20130228 00:00:00.000' UNION ALL
    SELECT 15, 1, 10.00, '20130328 00:00:00.000' UNION ALL
    SELECT 16, 1, 10.00, '20130428 00:00:00.000' UNION ALL
    SELECT 17, 1, 10.00, '20130528 00:00:00.000' UNION ALL
    SELECT 18, 1, 10.00, '20130628 00:00:00.000' UNION ALL
    SELECT 19, 1, 10.00, '20130728 00:00:00.000' UNION ALL
    SELECT 20, 1, 10.00, '20130828 00:00:00.000' UNION ALL
    SELECT 21, 1, 10.00, '20130928 00:00:00.000' UNION ALL
    SELECT 22, 1, 10.00, '20131028 00:00:00.000' UNION ALL
    SELECT 23, 1, 10.00, '20131128 00:00:00.000' UNION ALL
    SELECT 24, 1, 10.00, '20131228 00:00:00.000' UNION ALL
    SELECT 25, 2, 20.00, '20120128 00:00:00.000' UNION ALL
    SELECT 26, 2, 20.00, '20120228 00:00:00.000' UNION ALL
    SELECT 27, 2, 20.00, '20120328 00:00:00.000' UNION ALL
    SELECT 28, 2, 20.00, '20120428 00:00:00.000' UNION ALL
    SELECT 29, 2, 20.00, '20120528 00:00:00.000' UNION ALL
    SELECT 30, 2, 20.00, '20120628 00:00:00.000' UNION ALL
    SELECT 31, 2, 20.00, '20120728 00:00:00.000' UNION ALL
    SELECT 32, 2, 20.00, '20120828 00:00:00.000' UNION ALL
    SELECT 33, 2, 20.00, '20120928 00:00:00.000' UNION ALL
    SELECT 34, 2, 20.00, '20121028 00:00:00.000' UNION ALL
    SELECT 35, 2, 20.00, '20121128 00:00:00.000' UNION ALL
    SELECT 36, 2, 20.00, '20121228 00:00:00.000' UNION ALL
    SELECT 37, 2, 20.00, '20130128 00:00:00.000' UNION ALL
    SELECT 38, 2, 20.00, '20130228 00:00:00.000' UNION ALL
    SELECT 39, 2, 20.00, '20130328 00:00:00.000' UNION ALL
    SELECT 40, 2, 20.00, '20130428 00:00:00.000' UNION ALL
    SELECT 41, 2, 20.00, '20130528 00:00:00.000' UNION ALL
    SELECT 42, 2, 20.00, '20130628 00:00:00.000' UNION ALL
    SELECT 43, 2, 20.00, '20130728 00:00:00.000' UNION ALL
    SELECT 44, 2, 20.00, '20130828 00:00:00.000' UNION ALL
    SELECT 45, 2, 20.00, '20130928 00:00:00.000' UNION ALL
    SELECT 46, 2, 20.00, '20131028 00:00:00.000' UNION ALL
    SELECT 47, 2, 20.00, '20131128 00:00:00.000' UNION ALL
    SELECT 48, 2, 20.00, '20131228 00:00:00.000'
    COMMIT;
```

Comment: Yes.I have updated the question with my attempt.I have problem in working out the startingbalance.

Comment: Nearly there I am missing the last bit ,how to exclude the last 12 months.Could somebody help.I have updated the question

Comment: I think your question need reformulating. Either you want 12 row + sum of all other rows or you want 12 months + sum of all before 12 months. I also don't your output format. Do you need this sum in each of you rows? Or may be you want 13th row with sum of all transactions before 12 months?

Comment: @RomanPekar sorry for being unclear.I want to output last 12 rows(CreatedDate desc)for each account including an extra column which is sum of all transactions before 12 months) or as you might have suggested "return 13 rows ,which is composed of last 12 rows + 13th row with sum of all transactions before 12 months.Is it clearer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
with cte as (
    select
        row_number() over(partition by AccountNo order by CreatedDate desc) as rn,
        AccountNo, Amount, CreatedDate
    from TransactionsTest
), cte2 as (
    select
        c.AccountNo, c.CreatedDate, c.Amount, 0 as Ord
    from cte as c
    where rn <= 12
    union all
    select
        c.AccountNo, null as CreatedDate, sum(c.Amount) as Amount, 1 as Ord
    from cte as c
    where rn > 12
    group by c.AccountNo
)
select
    AccountNo, CreatedDate, Amount
from cte2
order by AccountNo, Ord, CreatedDate
```

**<kbd>[sql fiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/9ce73/5)</kbd>**

Comment: That works fantastically.This is exactly what I want.One question is row_number compatible with sql 2005.I have 2008 on my laptop now but at work will be sql 2005.

Comment: @RomanPekar.I was re-reading the query you wrote and Could you explain what does "0 as Ord" and "1 as Ord" mean to me?Many thanks

Comment: @user231465 it's additional column which helps total row go after all rows with dates